# How to let user upload image into JavaScript source instead of using default image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript file and inside of it I have a specific line of code I'm trying to edit:

```
outlineImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
        outlineImage.src = "images/watermelon-duck-outline.png";
```

How can I let the users upload their own image here?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to directly let the user specify their own image there.  You need to make a form where a user can upload the image and server-side script to receive the upload image and store it on your server, and then rewrite your code to output whatever the user uploaded.  And to make it user-specific you would need some kind of system in place to specify the picture belongs to the user, like a login system or at least a cookie with an id or something.  In other words, there are a lot of moving parts involved in something like this.